# Why does my topology type not work from a different publication?

Tags: topology-manager

In Topology Manager I have a single Topology Type, called "Standard web site". It has a staging and a live target. I have used this to publish successfully.

I have now added a new publication, which is in a different blueprinting chain so I've also created a new business process type, wired it up to my topology type, and selected it in the properties of my publication.

When I try to publish, I don't see anything in the Items to publish. Is there something else I need to do beyond just using my existing topology configuration?

Comment: As you have not mentioned , check if you have added the `Mapping` for your `PublicationId` and the `WebApplicationId` using `Add-TtmMapping` command ?

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh - you are correct. If you put this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You can also use the [Publication Mappings](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/m/mediagallery/1309) extension to map a Publication to a Web Application. We plan to include this in a future version of SDL Web, so feedback (on that page) or questions (here on Tridion Stack Exchange) are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the Mapping for your `PublicationId` and the `WebApplicationId` using **`Add-TtmMapping`** command

Useful References-

1. SDL Docs [Mapping a Publication to a Web application](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-92B9DFBA-E3F6-43F1-8B36-D8B064218399)
2. Video tutorial explaining all the steps to be followed for Topology Management - 
   [SDL Web 8 Topology Manager Demo](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/w/web8-training/900.sdl-web-8-topology-manager-demo)
   (You are missing Step -7 here)